# How to host a pdf doc as a webpage

Tags: html, css, pdf, responsive-design

Is there a better way to convert a pdf to html code so that it can be hosted on a website? I have found converters like these https://pdf.online/convert-pdf-to-html

would like to know if there is a much better way?

Also Can the html code of a pdf using these converters be made mobile responsive??

Want to host an already pdf doc as a mobile responsive webpage

Comment: Think this way... do you think that a printed page would reflow if I folded it in half? The answer is no. PDF is a print representation of a page or set of pages. You can try and convert it to HTML but you will likely get a whole bunch of absolute positioned div's

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to achieve.
As for making the design/content public you could just host the file itself. For example https://example.com/home.pdf

But that does not allow you to include Links and also PDF is not made to be responsive.

You may use a converter but to make it a proper website you will still have to tweak its resulting HTML and CSS.

Comment: Apologies! I could do home.pdf but that won't work on mobile like it works on the desktop right? Meaning if I open the same link on my phone it would download the pdf instead of giving in browser experience.So the goal is to have in browser experience on mobile and to achieve that was converting pdf to html code and how that is being converted it is not mobile responsive

Comment: Well, then I guess you still have to do adjustments to it. If you don't like to code you might as well get an Interface like Webflow, Wordpress or something and you design it there to match the original PDF.